# How to wrap multiple textbox wrap together?

Tags: c#, wpf, wrappanel

I want to `1.` from the following image:

[image]

My code is here:

```
<WrapPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Title: " Style="{StaticResource Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description" Style="{StaticResource Normal}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</WrapPanel>
```

But if `Description` text is short, shown like `2.`, if `Description` text is long, shown like `3.`

How to do this like `1.`?

Comment: WrapPanels won't do that, i can tell you that much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have solve my question using `Run`:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"> 
    <Run Text="Title: " Style="{StaticResource TitleRun}"/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Description,Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource NormalRun}"/>                                
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep adding them to the Grid with 2 columns and n number of rows, adding new rows/colls as you add them.

You can create a behaviour for that.

Comment: The problem is that there should be one non-rectangular TextBlock that wraps around another one.

Comment: A custom panel then?:) Should it act like auto wrap?

Comment: Am I right in saying that text of the individual textboxes mustn't be wrapped?